# How to fill the white-space with info while leaving the rest unchanged?

Tags: python, notepad++

I am constructing scenery for a Flight Simulator and need to figure out how to edit many lines in a text file (3,579,189 of them).

I have TextCrawler Pro, Node, Python SVN and Notepad++ as tools.

Raw, pre-edit portion:

```
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.017498354525,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.016478251402,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750598748133,42.017193264943,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.017498354525,0


POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.085882815878,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.082008734634,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.751045507507,42.082126409633,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750281907508,42.083166574215,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750781149174,42.084212672130,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.085882815878,0


POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.088955814831,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750456566883,42.087544672125,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.751642899173,42.088273325249,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.751461052298,42.088916154415,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.088955814831,0
```

With Notepad++'s replace function, it is easy enough to add the `POLYGON_POINT` line. Now I need some assistance in making it appear as so:

```
BEGIN_POLYGON
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.017498354525,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.016478251402,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750598748133,42.017193264943,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.017498354525,0
END_POLY
BEGIN_POLYGON
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.085882815878,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.082008734634,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.751045507507,42.082126409633,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750281907508,42.083166574215,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750781149174,42.084212672130,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.085882815878,0
END_POLY
BEGIN_POLYGON
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.088955814831,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750456566883,42.087544672125,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.751642899173,42.088273325249,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.751461052298,42.088916154415,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.088955814831,0
```

i.e. add `BEGIN_POLYGON` before each block and `END_POLY` after each.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in Notepad++? Or Python? What's your proposed method? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I would group the lines by being blank or not, using `itertools.groupby` (only taking the non-blank groups with the `if k` condition), and add the header/footer for each group. Then flatten the groups using `itertools.chain`

```
import itertools

with open("file.txt") as f, open("fileout.txt","w") as fw:
    fw.writelines(itertools.chain.from_iterable([["BEGIN_POLYGON\n"]+list(v)+["END_POLYGON\n"] for k,v in itertools.groupby(f,key = lambda l : bool(l.strip())) if k]))
```

`key = lambda l : bool(l.strip()))` is the grouping key: test for empty line but for line termination

this method doesn't need to read the file fully, so it's suited for very big files. It processes the file line by line so it doesn't hog the memory.

Comment: "Did you ever know that you're my heeerrrooooo..." I owe you whatever you'd like mon amie!

Comment: @BrianBash don't forget to vote and accept the answer that was useful for you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you are welcome, do you think my answer was correct here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976157/part-2-of-a-successful-outcome-regarding-white-space-filling/46976642#46976642 I was based on your answer but I don't fully know if I understood the question

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution using `sed`

```
cat -s file.txt |\
    sed -e 's/^$/END_POLY\nBEGIN_POLYGON/'\
    -e '1i BEGIN_POLYGON'\
    -e '$a END_POLY'
```

- `cat -s` squeezes all blank lines into one
- the first sed replace blank lines with END_POLY and BEGIN_POLYGON tags
- the second and last sed prepends and appends the remaining tags to the output