# Part 2 of a successful outcome regarding white-space filling

Tags: python, duplicates

So, my first question was answered correctly. For reference you can go here...

[How to fill the white-space with info while leaving the rest unchanged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969719/how-to-fill-the-white-space-with-info-while-leaving-the-rest-unchanged/46969904#46969904)

In short, I needed this...

```
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.017498354525,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.016478251402,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750598748133,42.017193264943,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.017498354525,0


POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.085882815878,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.082008734634,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.751045507507,42.082126409633,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750281907508,42.083166574215,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750781149174,42.084212672130,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.085882815878,0
```

To become this...

```
BEGIN_POLYGON
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.017498354525,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.016478251402,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750598748133,42.017193264943,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.017498354525,0
END_POLY
BEGIN_POLYGON
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.085882815878,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.082008734634,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.751045507507,42.082126409633,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750281907508,42.083166574215,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750781149174,42.084212672130,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.085882815878,0
END_POLY
```

Which was succesfully accomplished with a python script. Now I have found that I need to remove duplicate lines, specifically the last line from each block. That line closes the polygon but the building batch gives an error because it closes the polygon on it's own. Basically I need it to be this at the end of it all...

```
BEGIN_POLYGON
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.017498354525,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.016478251402,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750598748133,42.017193264943,0
END_POLY
BEGIN_POLYGON
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.085882815878,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750000000217,42.082008734634,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.751045507507,42.082126409633,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750281907508,42.083166574215,0
POLYGON_POINT -79.750781149174,42.084212672130,0
END_POLY
```

and there are 3,415,978 lines to go through. Every other duplicate remover takes away the white space and all the wording. Hmmm

Comment: Keep track of the last line you read and do not write that if current line is `END POLY`.

Comment: do you want to preserve the order? did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, keep a reference to the previous line:

```
with open('in.txt') as fin, open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    prev = None
    for i, line in enumerate(fin):
      if line.strip() != 'END_POLY' and prev:
        fout.write(prev)
      prev = line
      if not i % 10000:
        print('Processing line {}'.format(i))
    fout.write(line)
```

Comment: got this....   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:\X-Plane 11\addpoly.py", line 9, in <module>
    fout.write(prev)
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

Comment: import itertools

     with open("y.txt") as f, open("yout.txt","w") as fw:
    
 fw.writelines(itertools.chain.from_iterable([["BEGIN_POLYGON\n"]+list(v)+["END_POLY\n"] for k,v in itertools.groupby(f,key = lambda l : bool(l.strip())) if k]))
with open('yout.txt') as fin, open('yout1.txt', 'w') as fout:
    prev = None
    for i, line in enumerate(fin):
      if line.strip() != 'END_POLY':
          fout.write(prev)
      prev = line
      if not i % 10000:
        print('Processing line {}'.format(i))
    fout.write(line)

Comment: Added the None check

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want duplicated data, you can trasform the list into set, then into list (taking the @Jean-François Fabre code from the other question an little modific):

```
import itertools, collections

with open("file.txt") as f, open("fileout.txt","w") as fw:
    fw.writelines(itertools.chain.from_iterable([["BEGIN_POLYGON\n"]+list(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(v).keys())+["END_POLYGON\n"] for k,v in itertools.groupby(f,key = lambda l : bool(l.strip())) if k]))
```

as you can see, if you do:

```
print(list(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys([1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,5,3,3,3,3,3]).keys()))
```

it will be -> `[1, 2, 5, 3]` and yo preserve the order

Comment: err, turning the list into set changes the order. Not sure OP wants that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I edited the answer, and now it preserve the order

Answer (score 0):

Although not in python, these types of editing is quite straighforward if you use `sed`

```
sed 'N;s/.*\n\(END_POLY\)/\1/' file.txt
```

Basically what it does is that it uses `N` to read 2 lines at a time, if the second line contains the string `END_POLY`, it removes the first line, leaving only `END_POLY`